# Rebase to remove unwanted commits from a branch

Tags: git, rebase

I have a branch `master` that I branched off of and I want to merge my changes into a `release` branch. The thing is tho, since I branched off of `master` I have commits in my branch that don't need to go into the `release` branch. I tried rebasing like `git rebase origin/release` but that doesn't seem to remove the unwanted commits. How can I remove the unwanted commits and have my work on top of the release work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you're giving the wrong rebase command. Say

```
git switch mybranch
git rebase --onto release master mybranch
```